# Let's play tennis

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

I suddenly really want to play tennis, but alas I do not have a court!

Surprise! This is where you come in.

You have to print a tennis court for me, but you have to do it in the fewest bytes possible because of confidential reasons.

### Tennis court

```
---------
|       |
---------
|   |   |
xxxxxxxxx
|   |   |
---------
|       |
---------
```

### This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Trailing newline allowed?

Comment: @ErikGolferエリックゴルファー yes

Comment: Can the large gaps in row 2 and 8 be done using tabs?

Comment: @Flp.Tkc, I don't think so. I think since nobody else in the six answers already posted knew that, it would be unfair.

Comment: Are extra spaces allowed (as long as the output looks like the picture)?

Comment: @GB, extra spaces where?

Comment: Extra spaces after the end of an output line (before newline).

Comment: @GB, no. You may only have an optional trailing newline

Comment: This is a surprisingly tricky challenge for such a short output string! I like it. :)

Comment: You can just call this challenge a "Dennis court" since everybody knows who will win anyway... :)

Comment: 33 votes, 33 answers...

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek Too early! DJMcMayhem won, in fact.

Comment: @FlipTack 36 votes, 36 answers...

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek 40 votes, 40 answers now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ａ←⁹ｗ５+7ｑ⁴‟５ｎ┼
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjIxJXUyMTkwJXUyMDc5JXVGRjU3JXVGRjE1KzcldUZGNTEldTIwNzQldTIwMUYldUZGMTUldUZGNEUldTI1M0M_,v=8)

Answer (score 13):

## Python 2, 65 bytes

```python
s='-','|'+' '*7,'-','|   ','x'
for i in s+s[3::-1]:print(i*9)[:9]
```

Flp.Tkc saved a byte.

Comment: That's some crazy slicing. Nice!

Comment: You can use `'|'+' '*7` for the second string in `s` to save a byte!

Answer (score 12):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <del>29</del> <del>27</del> 26 bytes

```
'-9×©'|ð4×«Dûs®s¨¨ûû'x5×»û
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=Jy05w5fCqSd8w7A0w5fCq0TDu3PCrnPCqMKow7vDuyd4NcOXwrvDuw&input=)

```
'-9×©                      Push "---------" and store it as temporary value
     '|ð4×«Dûs             Push palindromized("|    ") = "|       |"
                           and push "|    "
              ®            Push "---------" again
               s¨¨û        Strip the last 2 characters from "|    " and push palindromized("|  ") = "|   |"
                   û       Palindromize last item -> "|   |   |"
                    'x5×   Push "xxxxx"
                        »  Join everything with newlines
                         û Palindromize the result and implicitly display it
```

Comment: `9'-×D'|4ð×«©ûs®¨'|«û5'x×»û` tried refactoring a little, can't break 26.

Comment: Another [26 bytes alternative](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fiUtBt6JG6VHDItMi30MrDm3kOrT3cI8xiH9h0@EVXnqHduk96uj6/x8A).

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3 -  <s>73</s> 72 bytes

```py
d=b,a,c='|       |','-'*9,'|   |   |'
print(a,*d,'x'*9,c,a,b,a,sep='\n')
```

**Python 3.6** - 75 bytes

```py
x=f"{'-'*9}\n|{' '*7}|\n{'-'*9}\n|   |   |\n"
print(x,'x'*9,x[::-1],sep='')
```

Credit goes to [flp-tkc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/60919/flp-tkc). Thank you :)

[Try here!](https://repl.it/EszP/2)

Answer (score 6):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), <s>64</s> 56 bytes

```
/f/---//e/   //a/fff
|ee |
fff
//d/|e|e|
/adxxxxxxxxx
da
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#NcaxDQAxCMXQnilYAHkmJPgzpGB3kivOr/EiIgIad4dEkk23j30HxfRjZJ0/q9y9)

Another 56 byte solution:

```
/f/---//e/|   //a/fff
e    |
fff
//d/ee|
/adxxxxxxxxx
da
```

Answer (score 6):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 25 bytes

```
9é-ÄÙÒ r|$.4äGMãlr|jj.kÒX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#ASMA3P//OcOpLcOEw5nDkiByfCQuNMOkR03Do2xyfGpqLmvDklj//w)

This should be 23 bytes:

```
9é-ÄÙÒ r|$.4äMÒXãkr|jj.
```

But I ran into several bugs while creating it. :(

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“¡⁵÷ḞȯḤɼ’b4ị“- x|”s5ŒBŒḄY
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcwqHigbXDt-G4nsiv4bikybzigJliNOG7i-KAnC0geHzigJ1zNcWSQsWS4biEWQ&input=)**

I had hoped to use the 1,3,1 quarter court repetition, but can't squeeze that into less (a raw version being 28: `“ßṂuB’b4s3x“¢¤¢‘ị“- x|”ŒBŒḄY`).

#### How?

```
“¡⁵÷ḞȯḤɼ’b4ị“- x|”s5ŒBŒḄY - Main link: no arguments
“¡⁵÷ḞȯḤɼ’                 - base 250 number: 375116358919167
         b4               - convert to base 4:
                                [1,1,1,1,1,0,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,2,2,2,0,3,3,3,3,3]
           ị“- x|”        - index into character list "- x|" (1-based):
                                "-----|    -----|   |xxxxx"
                  s5      - split into chunks of length 5:
                               ["-----","|    ","-----","|   |","xxxxx"]
                    ŒB    - bounce (vectorises):
                               ["---------","|        |","---------","|   |   |","xxxxxxxxx"]
                      ŒḄ  - bounce (non-vectorising version):
                               ["---------","|        |","---------","|   |   |","xxxxxxxxx","|   |   |","---------","|        |","---------"]
                        Y - join with line feeds:
                          - implicit print
```

Answer (score 5):

## J, <s>70</s> <s>54</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

*Saved a byte thanks to Zgarb!*

```
9 9$'-| |-| | |x| | |'#~3 9 1 7{~4#.inv 1851926050
```

Some standard compression technique, using a compressed RLE.

```
   9 9$'-| |-| | |x| | |'#~3 9 1 7{~4#.inv 1851926050
---------
|       |
---------
|   |   |
xxxxxxxxx
|   |   |
---------
|       |
---------
```

Comment: Reorder and save a byte: `9 9$'-| |-| | |x| | |'#~3 9 1 7{~4#.inv 1851926050`

Comment: @Zgarb ah, nice!

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>86</s> <s>84</s> <s>83</s> 81 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes, thanks to Neil*

```js
a=`---------
`;a+=`|       |
`+a;b=`|   |   |
`;console.log(a+b+`xxxxxxxxx
`+b+a)
```

#### Alternate method #1, 93 bytes

```js
console.log('01232101242421512424210123210'.replace(/./g,n=>`-
|  x`[n].repeat('911739'[n])))
```

#### Alternate method #2, 86 bytes

Suggested by Neil:

```js
console.log(`-${s=`
       |
-
   |
`}x${s}-`.replace(/.*/g,s=>s.repeat(9).slice(-9)))
```

#### Alternate method #3, 91 bytes

A recursive approach:

```js
console.log((f=(n,c=`xxxx
|   |   |
---------
|       |
`[n]||'-')=>~n--?c+f(n)+c:'x')(43))
```

Comment: You can make this a function to save a few bytes.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I'm not sure it's allowed to just return the output here: _You have to print a tennis court_

Comment: Simple run length encoding is a byte shorter than your alternate method: `console.log('-9\n| 7|\n-9\n| 3| 3|\nx9\n| 3| 3|\n-9\n| 7|\n-9'.replace(/.\d/g,s=>s[0].repeat(s[1])))` (replace `\n` with newline obviously).

Comment: Another 92-byte formulation: `console.log('-\n       |\n-\n   |\nx\n   |\n-\n       |\n-'.replace(/.*/g,s=>s.repeat(9).slice(-9)))`.

Comment: Sorry, there are supposed to be 7 or 3 spaces before each `|` as appropriate instead of the single space that appears in my comment.

Comment: Oh, and just converting your main answer to separate statements saves 2 bytes, since you don't need the extra set of `()`s.

Comment: @Neil I really like your `repeat(9).slice(-9)` idea!

Comment: I've since beaten those methods, even without ES6 features, so I've added it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 60 bytes

```
-4.upto(4){|i|puts''.rjust(9,%w{x |%3s - |%7s -}[i.abs]%'')}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
-4.upto(4){|i|                    #iterate -4 to 4.
   puts''.rjust(9,                #Print the null string right justified to length 9 padded by repititions of
   %w{x |%3s - |%7s -}[i.abs]%'') #the string from the %w{} array modified like sprintf by the % operator
}                                 #so that %Ns is replaced by N spaces.
```

Answer (score 4):

## bash/Unix tools, <s>58</s> 57 bytes

```
dc<<<4o16i3FFFFp20002prp20202p15555pszpszfp|tr 0-3 ' x|-'
```

Only four characters other than newline appear in the desired output, allowing each line to be coded as a base-4 number. These numbers are  then written in hexadecimal in the script, for brevity.

The Unix calculator dc is used both for the base-16 to base-4 conversion and for stack manipulation to allow easy repetition of lines in the right places.

*Edit:* Shaved one byte off by swapping two of the base-4 digits used to code characters, permitting the tr command to be one byte shorter than the previous version.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript, 85 bytes

```
console.log('---|  ---| |xxx| |---|  ---'.replace(/(.)((.).)/g,'$1$3$3$2$3$3$3$1\n'))
```

Answer (score 4):

## [SOGL 0.5](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md) (non-competing)

```
 -9*"D√⅜‘⁴"Hοr‘¹q x9*o±
```

Explanation:

```
"'|⁶.f,‘9n_h¹q x9*o±
"'|⁶.f,‘              pushes "------------------|       ||   |   |"
        9n            splits into chunks of 9
                       stack: [["---------","---------","|       |","|   |   |"]]
          _           puts all the contents of the array into the stack
                       stack: ["---------","|       |","---------","|   |   |"]
           h          swaps the 2nd from top with 3rd from top
            ¹         turns back into array
                       stack: [["---------","|       |","---------","|   |   |"]]
             q        outputs the array without popping it from stack
               x      push "x"
                       stack: [["---------","|       |","---------","|   |   |"], "x"]
                9*    repeat it 9 times
                       stack: [["---------","|       |","---------","|   |   |"], "xxxxxxxxx"]
                  o   output that
                   ±  reverse the array
implicitly output the reversed array
```

So how does the compressed string work?

The string converted from base250 to binary is
`1000000100111110010100001110100000001100010001`

and approxametally what it does:

```
100 boxstring (a custom dictionary string with chars " -/\|_\n")
000010 choose only the "-"s
01111 with length of 15+(different chars used)+2 = 18 chars
there is only 1 char type, so results in "------------------"
100 another boxsting
101000 choosing " " and "|"
01110 with length of 14+(different chars used)+2 = 18 chars
100000001100010001 the data; 0 = " " and 1 = "|"
has "------------------" and "|       ||   |   |" and just joins them together
```

non-competing, because language postdates the challenge. And this challenge is only a day old. I knew I should've put something up yesterday. I did this as a test for my language and it ended up too good not to post. Pretty sure this is golfable more too.

Answer (score 3):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 59 bytes

```
/_/---------
//s/   /_|ss |
_|s|s|
xxxxxxxxx
|s|s|
_|ss |
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#@68fr68LA1z6@sX6CgoK@vE1xcUKNVxACgi5KmCAC8KHyf7/DwA)

[Outgolfed...](//ppcg.lol/a/103607/41024)

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (ES6), 86 bytes:

```
a=`---------
|       |
---------`;b=`|   |   |
`;console.log(a+`
`+b+`xxxxxxxxx
`+b+a)
```

Test here:

```js
a=`---------
|       |
---------`;b=`|   |   |
`;console.log(a+`
`+b+`xxxxxxxxx
`+b+a)
```

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by adding a newline at the start of `b`, as this means that you can remove the newline after `xxxxxxxxx` and the one that you add between `a` and `b`. You can save a further 3 bytes by setting `a` to `---------` first and then concatenating the second row and a to itself.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 26 bytes

```
'-5×©'|4úD®sÂðñ)í€û»'x5×»û
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=Jy01w5fCqSd8NMO6RMKuc8OCw7DDsSnDreKCrMO7wrsneDXDl8K7w7s&input=)

Comment: [Better golf this down more!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103788/12537)

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>66</s> 62 bytes

This is the original answer (66 bytes):

```
<?=$a="---------
|       |
---------
|   |   |
xxxx",x,strrev($a);
```

It generates a notice because of the unknown constant `x`. The notice can be suppressed by setting `error_reporting=0` in `php.ini` or in the command line:

```
$ php -d error_reporting=0 tennis.php
```

The last line of the output doesn't end with a newline character.

---

The updated answer (62 bytes), improving an improvement suggested by  @Titus:

```
<?=$a=($b="---------
|   ")."    |
$b|   |
xxxx",x,strrev($a);
```

Run it without a configuration file (it defaults with `error_reporting=0` this way):

```
$ php -n tennis.php
```

Both versions of the code contain literal new lines embedded in the string (1 byte shorter than `\n`) and cannot we unwrapped.

Comment: Notices are turned off in the default config; no need for `-d error_reporting=0`, just use `-n`.

Comment: I count 66. You can make them 65 with `<?=$a=($b="---------\n|")."...`.

Comment: @Titus I like your suggestion. `-n` is much shorter than `-d error_reporting=0` :-) There are, indeed, only 66 useful chars in the answer. I counted them using `ls -l` and forgot my `vi` is configured to ensure the file ends with a new line. I improved your improvement and squeezed 3 more bytes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, <s>28</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
\|ddsssd7*.X--||"R\x5*nJs
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%5C%7Cddsssd7%2a.X--%7C%7C%22R%5Cx5%2anJs)

```
       d7*                -    " " * 7
          .X--||"         -   grid(^, corners="-", sides="-", left="|", right="|")
\|dds                     -     "|  "
     s                    -    palindromise(^)
      s                   -   palindromise(^)
                  \x5*    -   "x" * 5
                      nJ  -  "\n".join(^)
                        s - palindromise(^)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 52 bytes

```
puts [b=[a=?-*9,"|%8s"%?|,a],c="|   |   |",?x*9,c,b]
```

Using the double simmetry, the lines are: `0-1-0 / 2-3-2 / 0-1-0`, the loop can be easily unrolled and the nested list is flattened on output.

Answer (score 2):

### J, 36 bytes

```
9$'-'([,(' '4}]),[,],'x',:])9$'|   '
```

This works on the REPL, which is the standard way of using J:

```
   9$'-'([,(' '4}]),[,],'x',:])9$'|   '
---------
|       |
---------
|   |   |
xxxxxxxxx
|   |   |
---------
|       |
---------
```

With **41 bytes**, I can print the result to STDOUT:

```
echo 9$'-'([,(' '4}]),[,],'x',:])9$'|   '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@anJGvYKmirquuEa2joa6gblIbq6kTrROro16hrmMVqwmUq1FQUFD//x8A)

### Explanation

I construct the tennis court one row at a time.

```
9$'-'([,(' '4}]),[,],'x',:])9$'|   '
                            9$'|   '  The string repeated to length 9: y = '|   |   |'
  '-'(                     )          Apply this verb to x = '-' and y:
                     'x',:]            y with a row of 'x'-chars above it.
                                       This is a 2x9 matrix, and "," now works by
                                       prepending new rows to it.
                   ],                  Prepend another y.
                 [,                    Prepend x, which is repeated to a row of length 9.
        (' '4}]),                      Prepend y with 4th character replaced by a space.
      [,                               Prepend x again.
                                      Now we have this 6x9 matrix:
                                       ---------
                                       |       |
                                       ---------
                                       |   |   |
                                       xxxxxxxxx
                                       |   |   | 
9$                                    Repeat it to have 9 rows.
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 72 bytes

```php
<?=$a="---------
",$b="|       |
$a",$c="|   |   |
","xxxxxxxxx
$c$a$b";
```

I almost hate it when it´s shorter like this than with calculating a little.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>67</s> 66 bytes

```powershell
($a='-'*9)
($b="|       |")
$a
($c="|   "*2+"|")
'x'*9
$c
$a
$b
$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6@hkmirrquuZanJpaGSZKtUowABNUqaXCqJQLFkiJiSlpG2EkhQvQKomEslGSSrkgQk//8HAA)

Just some string multiplication, setting variables, and ensuring they're encapsulated in parens to place copies on the pipeline. The default `Write-Output` at program completion gives us newlines between for free.

*Thanks to @ConnorLSW for saving an obvious byte.*

Comment: `$(' '*7)` is actually 8 chars, would be shorter to just do `|       |` as spaces.

Comment: @ConnorLSW Oh, haha. Thanks for the obvious golf! :D

Comment: just paying you back for the `ToLower()` save on my other answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

## 05AB1E, 25 bytes

```
'-9×©'|ð4×«û®…|  ûû'x5×»û
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/#MlEsh)

Explanation:

```
'-9×                       # Push "---------"
    ©                      # Store in register_c
     '|ð4×«                # Push "|    "
           û               # Palindromize, giving "|       |"
            ®              # Retrieve from register_c
             …|            # Push "|  "
                 ûû        # Palindromize twice, giving "|   |   |"
                   'x5×    # Push "xxxxx"
                       »   # Join by newlines
                        û  # Palindromize
                           # Implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, 32 bytes

```
9i-^[Y3pO||^[7i ^[YGPkP4lr|YpO^[9ix^[
```

This will print the tennis court into a vim buffer. `^M` represents the Enter key (0x0d) and `^[` is the Escape key (0x1b). You can run these keystrokes/code by saving them to a file and running

```
vim -s <filename> -u NONE
```

#### Printing to stdout

If it has to be printed to stdout instead, you could save the buffer to a file (I used "a") and use whichever shell `vim` is set to use (I used `bash`) as well as the `cat` program in order to print the tennis court to stdout (51 bytes):

```
9i-^[Y3pO||^[7i ^[YGPkP4lr|YpO^[9ix^[:w!a|sil !cat %^M:q^M
```

It's the same as the earlier version but with `:w!a|sil !cat %^M:q^M` added onto the end

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 75 bytes

```python
a,b,c='-'*9,'|       |','|   |   |'
for e in[a,b,a,c,'x'*9,c,a,b,a]:print e
```

Uses variables borrowed from @GurupadMamadapur

Alternative also for 75

```python
a,b,c='-'*9,'|       |','|   |   |'
print'\n'.join([a,b,a,c,'x'*9,c,a,b,a])
```

Answer (score 1):

## Emacs, <s>43</s> 35 keystrokes

<kbd>M-9</kbd> `x` <kbd>RET</kbd> : nine x's, return
<kbd>C-SPC</kbd> : set mark
`|` <kbd>M-3</kbd> <kbd>SPC</kbd> `|` <kbd>M-3</kbd> <kbd>SPC</kbd> `|` <kbd>RET</kbd> : pipe, three spaces, pipe, three spaces, pipe, return
<kbd>M-9</kbd> `-` <kbd>RET</kbd> : nine hyphens, return
`|` <kbd>M-7</kbd> <kbd>SPC</kbd> `|` <kbd>RET</kbd> : pipe, seven spaces, pipe, return
<kbd>M-9</kbd> `-` <kbd>RET</kbd> : nine hyphens, return
<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> : exchange point and mark, selecting region
<kbd>M-w</kbd> : copy region
<kbd>C-p</kbd> : previous line
<kbd>C-y</kbd> : yank copied text
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `rev-r` <kbd>RET</kbd> : execute `reverse-region` command

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 82 Bytes.

```
y=[[---------
|       |
---------
]]z="|   |   |\n"io.write(y,z,"xxxxxxxxx\n",z,y)
```

I tried many methods, and yet this one proved the victor.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 33 bytes

This question had 33 upvotes, and there were 33 answers, so I just had to post a 33 byte solution...

```
9:45;T`|    `wT`|   |`4dT5:120;w"
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@29pZWJqHZJQowAECeUQRk2CSUqIqZWhkYF1udL//wA)

---

### Explanation

The code can be split into several parts, to make it easier to understand. The first part works like so:

```
9:45;    \ Push the char '-' 9 times
T        \ Push 10, which is a linefeed
`|    `  \ Push these charcodes
```

The stack is now:

```
---------
|
```

The mirror operator, `w`, then mirrors the whole stack, producing:

```
---------
|       |
---------
```

Then:

```
T        \ Push a linefeed
`|   |`  \ Push these chars
4d       \ Copy the last 4 characters
T        \ Push a linefeed
5:120;   \ Push the char 'x', 5 times
```

The stack is now beginning to look like the tennis court:

```
---------
|       |
---------
|   |   |
xxxxx
```

To finish it, we use the mirror operator `w` once more, which reflects this string to produce the full tennis court.

```
---------
|       |
---------
|   |   |
xxxxxxxxx
|   |   |
---------
|       |
---------
```

All that's left now is to print, which is done by the `"` character.

Answer (score 1):

**Unix Shell; using dc and tr; 55 Bytes:**
( Optimization of Mitchell Spector solution )

```
dc<<<4o16i3FFFFp20002prp20202p15555psrfrp|tr 0-3 ' x|-'
```

**Others Solutions :
Using sed; 81 Bytes;**

```
echo "---|  ---| |xxx| |---|  ---"|sed "s/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)/\1\2\2\2\3\2\2\2\1\n/g"
```

**Using dc in function : 88 Bytes**

```
b(){ dc<<<2o16i1${1}p|tr '01' ' '$2;};(b FF -;b 01 \|;b FF -;b 11 \|)>f;cat f;b FF X;tac f
```

**or**

```
b(){ echo "obase=2;$1"|bc|tr '01' ' '$2;};(b 511 -;b 257 \|;b 511 -;b 273 \|)>f;cat f;b 511 X;tac f
```

**Using bc in function : 99 Bytes**

```
b(){ echo "obase=2;$1"|bc|tr '01' ' '$2;};(b 511 -;b 257 \|;b 511 -;b 273 \|)>f;cat f;b 511 X;tac f
```

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 56 bytes

```powershell
(('-'*9),'|       |'+'-'*9+'|   |   |'+'x'*9)[0..4+3..0]
```

Explanation: straightforward half-of-the-court

## Alternative, 68 bytes

```powershell
('-----','|    '+'-'*5+'|   |'+'x'*5)[($r=0..4+3..0)]|%{-join$_[$r]}
```

Explanation: quarter-of-the-court uses the same indexes for both row and column display

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 60 bytes

```python
for i in 0,7,0,3,-2,3,0,7,0:print(('-?x|'[i%4]+' '*i)*9)[:9]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPwUDHXMdAx1hH1whIgDlWBUWZeSUaGuq69hU16tGZqiax2uoK6lqZmlqWmtFWlrH//@vCAFeNAgTUcKGKgTFXBQwgieHVCwA)

Uses [Lynn's multiply-and-truncate method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103669/20260).

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 105 bytes

*Sure, I've already been beaten, but it ain't fun if you don't try!*

Actual answer:

```
a,c,d="---------","xxxxxxxxx","|   |   |"p=print p(a)p("|       |")p(a)p(d)p(c)p(d)p(a)p("|       |")p(a)
```

Less hardcoded:

```
a,b,c,d=("-"):rep(9),(" "):rep(7),("x"):rep(9),"|   |   |"p=print p(a)p("|"..b.."|")p(a)p(d)p(c)p(d)p(a)p("|"..b.."|")p(a)
```

Uses `String.rep` to make it less hardcoded (though it adds bytes!) (instead of `xxxxxxxxx`, write `("x"):rep(9)`)

*Just for fun, how easy would it be to just print it hardcoded?*

```
print([[---------
|       |
---------
|   |   |
xxxxxxxxx
|   |   |
---------
|       |
---------]])
```

*100 bytes. That's shorter than my code. :(*

Comment: Didn't checked the other ones, but the hardcoded version can be 98 characters if you remove the parenthesis: `print[[…]]`.

Comment: But the 2 mirrored halves approach is of course shorter: http://pastebin.com/pJLFEuck

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 116 bytes

```
@set s=---------
@for %%s in (%s% "|       |" %s% "|   |   |" %s:-=x% "|   |   |" %s% "|       |" %s%)do @echo %%~s
```

Conveniently, expansion of `for` variables happens *after* parsing, so I only have to quote the `|`s once. However, only the horizontal lines are sufficiently repetitive that using a variable saves bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 49 bytes

```
'x9*' 3*;2╟"|%s|%s|"%9'-*' 7*"|%s|"%9'-*k;RdX@i(i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@69eYamlrmCsZW30aOp8pRrVYhBSUrVU1wUKm2spIbjZ1kEpEQ6ZGpn//wMA)

Explanation:

```
'x9*' 3*;2╟"|%s|%s|"%9'-*' 7*"|%s|"%9'-*k;RdX@i(i
'x9*                                               "xxxxxxxxx"
    ' 3*;2╟"|%s|%s|"%                              "|   |   |"
                     '-*' 7*"|%s|"%                "|       |"
                                   9'-*            "---------"
                                       k;          push entire stack to list, duplicate it
                                         RdX       reverse one copy and remove the string of "x"s from it
                                            @i     flatten the other copy
                                              (i   flatten the first copy and implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 90 bytes

```
val l="-"*9
val g="\n|       |\n"
val s="\n|   |   |\n"
print(l+g+l+s+"x"*9+s+l+g+l)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 30 bytes

```
9Z"13+'|'7Z"yhhyy6M5(v'x'9Y"yP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@28ZpWRorK1eo24epVSZkVFZaeZrqlGmXqFuGalUGfD/PwA)

Answer (score 0):

## R, 121 bytes

```
m=rbind(a<-rep("-",9),b<-c("|",rep(" ",7),"|"),a,b,rep("x",9),b,a,b,a);m[c(4,6),5]="|";for(i in 1:9)cat(m[i,],"\n",sep="")
```

First time trying a Kolmogorov-Complexity challenge, not sure R is really suited for it.

#### Ungolfed:

```
a <- rep("-", 9)
b <- c("|", rep(" ", 7), "|")
m <- rbind(a, b, a, b, rep("x", 9), b, a, b, a)

m[c(4,6), 5] <- "|"

for(i in 1:9){
  cat(m[i,], "\n", sep = "")
}
```

#### Output:

```
---------
|       |
---------
|   |   |
xxxxxxxxx
|   |   |
---------
|       |
---------
```

Comment: `"|", rep(" ", 7), "|"` is longer than `"| ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ |"`

Comment: @12Me21 The code as I use it now requires a vector with each of the spaces in a separate string :/ so this wouldn't work with a direct substitution.

Comment: This does make me realise though that this answer is longer than just printing the raw code. Ohwell...

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 83 bytes

```
val(a,b)=("-"*9+"\n|   ","   |\n")  
val c=s"$a $b$a|$b"  
print(c+"x"*9+c.reverse)
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 97 bytes

```
n=11;i,k;f(){i=n/10%10;k=n++%10;printf("%c",k?"| -x"[i%2?i==5|2:k%8-1&&k-5|i*i%5-1]:10);i?f():0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## ///, 55 bytes

```
/l/---//s/   //m/
|s|s|
//a/lll
|s s|
lll/amxxxxxxxxxma
```

[**Try it online**](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L2wvLS0tLy9zLyAgIC8vbS8KfHN8c3wKLy9hL2xsbAp8cyBzfApsbGwvYW14eHh4eHh4eHhtYQ&input=)

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, <s>90</s> <s>86</s> <s>85</s> <s>81</s> 79 bytes

```
(format t"~5@{~@?
~}~4@{~2:*~@?
~}"#1="~9@{-~}""|~8t|"#1#"|   |   |""~9@{x~}"1)
```

<s>First we print out all arguments, and then we print them in reversed order (without `xxxxxxxxx`).</s>

Similiar solution, but instead of providing every variable directly I give (where it's efficient) control string which will output needed text.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, <s>68</s> <s>65</s> <s>62</s> <s>59</s> 57 bytes

```
M$="|   
L$="-"*9?L$?M$,M$?L$?M$*3?"x"*9?M$*3?L$?M$,M$?L$
```

(note the 3 trailing spaces in line 1)

Of course, this will work in many other dialects of BASIC.

Explained:

```
V$="|   " 'vertical line
H$="-"*9 'horizontal line
PRINT H$    '---------
PRINT V$,V$ '|       |
PRINT H$    '---------
PRINT V$*3  '|   |   |
PRINT "x"*9 'xxxxxxxxx
PRINT V$*3  '|   |   |
PRINT H$    '---------
PRINT V$,V$ '|       |
PRINT H$    '---------
```

`,` in `PRINT` is a tab, and luckily the default size is perfect for this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 98 bytes

Store repeated lines and add it all together.

```java
()->{String a="---------\n",b="|       |\n",c="|   |   |\n";return a+b+a+c+"xxxxxxxxx\n"+c+a+b+a;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 88 bytes

```
()=>{string a="---------\n",b="|   |   |\n";return(a+="|\t|\n"+a)+b+"xxxxxxxxx\n"+b+a;};
```

Anonymous function which returns the tennis court as a string.

Full program with ungolfed method:

```
using System;

namespace LetsPlayTennis
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<string> f =
            () =>
            {
                string a = "---------\n",
                    b = "|   |   |\n";
                return (a += "|\t|\n" + a)
                    + b
                    + "xxxxxxxxx\n"
                    + b
                    + a;
            };

            Console.WriteLine(f());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, 31 bytes

```
"--x--"M_X9WV:" || "M_WRsX3WR'|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fSVe3QldXyTc@wjI8zEpJoaZGAcgJDyqOMA4PUq/5//@/bg4A)

#### Explanation

We construct the even rows, then the odd rows, and then weave them together.

```
"--x--"M_X9WV:" || "M_WRsX3WR'|
                                 s is space (implicit)
       M                         Map this function
"--x--"                          to each character of this string:
        _X9                       Repeat the character 9 times
                                 The result is a list of five 9-character strings

                    M            Map this function
              " || "             to each character of this string:
                     _            The character
                      WR          wrapped on each side in
                        sX3       three spaces
                           WR'|   wrapped on each side in |
                                 The result is a list of four 9-character strings

           WV:                   Weave the two lists together (the : helps with parsing)
                                 Print, with each list element on its own line (-l flag)
```

Answer (score 0):

### [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), 89 bytes

```
1 WIDTH 13:P$="---------":S$="|       |":T$="|   |   |":PRINT $S$P$T$"xxxxxxxxx"T$P$S$P$
```

More abuse of the WIDTH directive to save multiple PRINTs.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 76 bytes

```r
"*"=strrep;write(c(a<-c(b<-"-"*9,"|       |",b,"|   |   |"),"x"*9,rev(a)),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X0lLyba4pKgotcC6vCizJFUjWSPRRjdZI8lGV0lXSctSR6lGAQJqlHSSIDwwVtLUUaoAKShKLdNI1NTUMdT8/x8A)