# Let's play tennis 2: east-west game

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

There is a challenge [Let's play tennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103605) by [Daniel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42854/daniel). He proposes to place a court in the North-South direction. My proposal is to create a court to play tennis in the East-West direction too.

You have to print a tennis court, but you have to do it in the fewest bytes possible because of confidential reasons.

### Tennis court

```
------x------
|  |  x  |  |
|  |--x--|  |
|  |  x  |  |
------x------
```

Original rules are:

- No extra spaces.
- No tabs as they would be unfair.
- One optional trailing newline is allowed.

### This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>13</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
«ω↕9:gＷ：ｔＣ‟┼
```

quad-palindromizes [a compressed corner of the field](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=ZGVidWdDb21wcmVzc2lvbiUzRHRydWUlM0JJLnNwbGl0JTYwJTVDbiU2MCV1RkYwMyV1RkYxQWNsaXAlMjhjb21wcmVzc1N0cmluZyUyOHAucCUyOSUyOSV1RkYwMyV1RkYzMSV1RkYyQyV1MjU3NyV1RkYxQiV1MjIxMSV1RkYyQyV1MDE1NyUyMC0lM0UlMjAldTAxNTclMjBieXRlcyV1RkYyRiV1MjIxOXAuRiUzQmNvbXByZXNzaW9uUGFydHMuc2xpY2UlMjgwJTJDLTElMjkubWFwJTI4YyUzRCUzRWMubWFwJTI4YyUzRCUzRSU1QmMudHlwZSUyQ2MubGVuZ3RoJTVEJTI5JTI5JXVGRjAzJXVGRjVCJXVGRjVCJXUyNTI0JXUyMDFDJXVGRjUxJTI2JXUyMDFFJXVGRjFBJXUyNTE0JUQ3JXVGRjM1JXVGRjFCJUY3JXVGRjNEJTIwJXVGRjBBJXVGRjNE,i=LS0tLS0tJTBBeCVCNiU3QyUyMCUyMCU3QyUyMCUyMHglQjYlN0MlMjAlMjAlN0MtLXg_,v=8).

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JUFCJXUwM0M5JXUyMTk1OSUzQWcldUZGMzcldUZGMUEldUZGNTQldUZGMjMldTIwMUYldTI1M0M_,v=8)

[11 bytes](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjRGJTI2JXUyNTI0YSV1RkYxQSolQjEldUZGMzNvJXUyMDFGJXUyNTND,v=8) with uppercase `X`es, using the fact that `/` compresses better than `x` and palindromizing would result in overlapping `/` and its mirror `\`, which results in `X`

Comment: See, my thinking when I first saw this question was "do I have enough time to go learn Canvas right now and then post a solution?" Evidently not :P

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

```python
s="------x------\n|  |  x  |  |\n|  |--x"
print s+s[-2::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWSRcMKiBUTF6NggIQVYDJGggXKKvEVVCUmVeiUKxdHK1rZGWlaxj7/z8A)

Prints the first half of the string followed by its reverse. It's boring but efficient. I tried extracting repeating parts of out `s`, especially the `-`, but didn't find anything shorter.

---

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes**

```python
for n in 6,0,2,0,6:x='-'*n+'  |  |'[n:];print x[::-1]+'x'+x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFPITNPwUzHQMcIiM2sKmzVddW18rTVFRRqgEg9Os8q1rqgKDOvRKEi2spK1zBWW71CXbvi/38A)

Using [Jo King's construction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174445/20260).

---

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 62 bytes**

```python
b='|  '*2
for r in'-'*6,b,'|  |--',b,'-'*6:print r+'x'+r[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8lWvUZBQV3LiCstv0ihSCEzT11XXctMJ0kHJF6jq6sOYoKErAqKMvNKFIq01SvUtYuirax0DWP//wcA)

Prints the first half of each line, followed by `'x'`, followed by the first half reversed.

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
↑²←⁶↓xx→x²↑²‖Ｏ¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMqtEBHwUjTmgvK9UlNK9FRMEMIuOSX5@koKFVUKCHEgjLTM0pAgggxJCNgJgalpuWkJpf4l6UW5SQWaFgdWqNp/f//f92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. By way of explanation I will show the result after each of the drawing commands up to the final reflection:

```
↑²        |
          |

     ------
←⁶        |
          |

    x------
↓xx x     |
          |

    x------
→x² x     |
    x--   |

    x------
↑²  x  |  |
    x--|  |
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>65</s> 62 bytes

```python
for n in 7,0,3,0,7:x="-"*n+"|  "*5;print(x[6:0:-1]+'x'+x[1:7])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFPITNPwVzHQMcYiM2tKmyVdJW08rSVahQUlLRMrQuKMvNKNCqizawMrHQNY7XVK9S1K6INrcxjNf//BwA)

Comment: Now *this* is the kind of string-slicing wizardry that I thought a Python answer to this challenge ought to have. Well played!

Answer (score 3):

## Dyalog APL, 36 bytes

```apl
(⌽,'x',⊢)(⊢⍪'--|  |'⍪⊖)'-'⍪1 6⍴'  |'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L/Go569OuoV6jqPuhZpagCJR72r1HV1axQUatSBzEdd0zTVdUEsQwWzR71b1EHiIJ3/FcCgAAA)

With a little help from [Adám](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47281505#47281505)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 75 bytes

```
s='-'*6;p='|  |';w=s+'x'+s;a=p+'  x  '+p;print(w,a,p+w[4:9]+p,a,w,sep='\n')
```

Probably golfable - I've never really tried [kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenges before.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcsxCoAwDAXQq2T7auqkCBp6EnXoIOhSgy1UoXevHd/w9Ivn7YdSgkWPbhK1yEQZkmxgvOAgziqD6CUCq@hz@dgk44xyWsdl3lkrkglHvZtHW8oP)

In Python 2 I could get it to **76 bytes**

```
s='-'*6;p='|  |';w=s+'x'+s;a=p+'  x  '+p
for i in w,a,p+w[4:9]+p,a,w:print i
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 55 bytes

```perl
say$_,x,~~reverse for('-'x6,'|  'x2,'|  |--')[0..2,1,0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIlXqdCp66uKLUstag4VSEtv0hDXVe9wkxHvUZBQb3CCEzX6Oqqa0Yb6OkZ6RjqGMT@//8vv6AkMz@v@L@ur6megaEBAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 35 bytes

```apl
' |-x'[(⍉⊖⍪1∘↓)⍣2⍉3⍪2,⍨676 28⊤⍨6⍴3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQYgFpBWV6jRrVCP1njU2/moa9qj3lWGjzpmPGqbrPmod7ERUNAYKGSk86h3hZm5mYKRxaOuJSD2o94txrH//wMA)

Comment: I just saw this now holy what

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, <s>42</s> <s>39</s> 34 bytes

```
RV@<P"|  |".[s'-]X2PE'-X6M_.'x.RV_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/KMzBJkCpRkGhRkkvulhdNzbCKMBVXTfCzDdeT71CLygs/v///7o5AA)

---

Alternate solution, also 34 bytes:

```
RV@<P"-0|  0|  |--"^0M_@<16RA6,t'x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/KMzBJkBJ16BGQQGEa3R1leIMfOMdbAzNghzNdErUK/7//6@bAwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>69</s> <s>68</s> 66 bytes

*-2 thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)*

```python
for l in"-","|  ","|  |--","|  ","-":l*=6;print l[:6]+"x"+l[5::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFHITNPSVdJR6lGQQFC1ugiuLpKVjlatmbWBUWZeSUKOdFWZrHaShVK2jnRplZWuoax//8DAA)

We cycle the following three patterns infinitely (6 times is sufficiently infinite for our purposes) and slice off the first 6 characters of each: `-`, `|`  , and `|  |--`. Then, to get the tennis court, we concatenate an `x` and the reverse of each line.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>25</s> 24 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
"
 -x|"•L®y[Â-Γ•5вèJ.º.∊
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fiUtBt6JG6VHDIp9D6yqjDzfpnpsM5Jhe2HR4hZfeoV16jzq6/v8HAA)

**<s>25</s> 24 bytes alternative:**

```
… -|•B°”Ñ•3вèJ3ä'x«».º.∊
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9vc2FiaWX//@KApiAtfOKAokLCsOKAncOR4oCiM9Cyw6hKM8OkJ3jCq8K7LsK6LuKIiv//)

**Explanation:**

```python
"\n -x|"       # Push string "\n -x|"
•L®y[Â-Γ•      # Push compressed number 5960566858660563
         5в    # Converted to Base-5 as list: 
               #  [2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,4,1,1,4,1,1,3,0,4,1,1,4,2,2,3]
è              # Index each digit into the string
 J             # And join the list together
               #  "\n -x|" and [2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,4,1,1,4,1,1,3,0,4,1,1,4,2,2,3]
               #   → "------x\n|  |  x\n|  |--x"
.º             # Intersect mirror everything horizontally
  .∊           # Intersect mirror everything vertically (and output implicitly)

… -|           # Push string " -|"
•B°”Ñ•         # Push compressed integer 193812448
      3в       # Converted to Base-3 as list: [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2,1,1]
è              # Index each digit into the string
 J             # And join the list together
               #  " -|" and [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2,1,1]
               #   → "------|  |  |  |--"
3ä             # Split the string into three parts: ["------","|  |  ","|  |--"]
  'x«         '# Append an "x" to each: ["------x","|  |  x","|  |--x"]
     »         # Join by newlines: "------x\n|  |  x\n|  |--x"
.º             # Intersect mirror everything horizontally
  .∊           # Intersect mirror everything vertically (and output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•L®y[Â-Γ•` is `5960566858660563` and `•B°”Ñ•` is `193812448`.

[Thanks to *@MagicOctopusUrn*'s ASCII-art generator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120966/52210) for [`•L®y[Â-Γ•5BžLR"\n -x|"‡`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/5tBul8OrDq08us8n6FHDwkPr0g9vMzI1dVJ61LBIqRhMAsWUnEDySsYmh5cfWgcigRILlbz@/9cFgwquGgUFIILQQD4A) and [`•B°”Ñ•3BžLR" -|"‡`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMip0MbHjXMPTwRyDR2OrrPJ0hJQbdG6VHDwv//AQ), after which the transliterate has been golfed further by swapping the number and string on the stack, use `в` instead of `B`, and index into the string with `è`.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 53 bytes

```
echo|:'x'(<6)}'-'(<2;~4+i.5)}13$3 5$'-|||',11$'--   '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I7/GSr1CXcPGTLNWXRdIG1nXmWhn6plq1hoaqxgrmKqo69bU1KjrGBoCWboKCgrq//8DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), 82 bytes

```
1 WIDTH 13:PRINT"------x------|  |  x  |  ||  |--x--|  ||  |  x  |  |------x------
```

Abusing the WIDTH directive saved me around 20 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
⌡x♠=Γτ^┼¢Δ¶─êiö$≥⌐▓
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=f578063de2e75ec59bff14c488699424f2a9b2&i=&a=1)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 34 bytes

```
+"x-| "@4\509 425 477 0@4\17218113
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/19bqUK3RkHJwSTG1MBSwcTIVMHE3FzBAMg3NDcytDA0NP7/HwA)

Port of K4 answer. 2 bytes saved with the `4\`, 1 byte lost due to the `+`

Answer (score 0):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 28 bytes

```
00000000: d3d5 0581 0a30 a9cb 55a3 a000 4415 60b2  .....0..U...D.`.
00000010: 06cc 03cb c179 0839 5d14 7d00            .....y.9].}.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcwxDsIwDIXhnVO8E1h2HbcNM1foiEScIBYYO3To2YMpDPyLB@t9vro/74/11Tv/OqNpM7DNAi7KKLk6zIqixBspiWFkHwD6xERLnAvd6PQVJAweawVrLKtMGTxrhjVJmFoYfx3GRvlKO/X@Bg)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“Þḅ“ H“ \’ṃ“-|x ”ŒBŒḄY
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5zD8x7uaAXSCh4gIuZRw8yHO5uBTN2aCoVHDXOPTnI6OunhjpbI//8B)**

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 25 bytes

```
13é-Äï5I  |<esc>ÄÙ4l5r-Îd^ãrx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/39D48Erdwy2H15t6KijUSANZM01yTIt0D/elxB1eXFTx/z8A)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 3133 e92d c4ef 3549 2020 7c1b c4d9 346c  13.-..5I  |...4l
00000010: 3572 2dce 645e e372 78                   5r-.d^.rx
```

Here was my process:

```
13é-Äï5I  |<esc>3<<ÄÙ4l5r-Gã<C-v>ërx
13é-Äï5I  |<esc>3<<ÄÙ4l5r-Î7|rx
13é-Äï5I  |<esc>3<<ÄÙ4l5r-Îãrx
13é-Äï5I  |<esc>ÄÙ4l5r-Îd^ãrx
```

Alternate version:

```
5I  |<esc>5ÄM4l5r-HÒ-G.Îxxãrx
```

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 3549 2020 7c1b 35c4 4d34 6c35 722d 48d2  5I  |.5.M4l5r-H.
00000010: 2d47 2ece 7878 e372 780a                 -G..xx.rx.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 76 bytes

```javascript
(a='----',A='|  |',b='--x--',B='  x  ')=>[p=a+b+a,q=A+B+A,A+b+A,q,p].join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBCoQwDEDR/Zwiu7Q0eoMI8RrDgNFRUaSpo4gL797Rv/tv1kO37jelvYj27fPA2SljcYckjBfAhdQ@cj5UMwKcAOi5eifW0AallSXUQUjuE1opfcrZpti8mtxZ3Gzpy8VGNzjv8x8)

- 68 bytes if array of strings allowed.

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 75 bytes

```javascript
_=>[p='x---',q='x|  ','x| -',q,p].map(c=>[...'1221330331221'].map(d=>c[d]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBCoAgFESv0u4r6KdybReRCNGKotQyokV3N6XVvHkzq751NOcSLu68HdMk0yA7FSQ8nHNgR4a3qoCVKJ2FHncdiMkvRISmbRshaiEKwL9Z2Rlle0qT8S76bcTNz2QiWXw)

- This one output 2d char array. I don't know if it can be golfed further more.

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org),<strike>98</strike> 80 bytes

```
foreach r[1 2 3 2 1][print pick["------x------""|  |  x  |  |""|  |--x--|  |"]r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@z8tvyg1MTlDoSjaUMFIwRiIDWOjC4oy80oUCjKTs6OVdMGgAkIpKdUoKABRBZisgXDBsmBubFHs//8A)

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, <s>60</s> 59 bytes

*-1 bytes thanks @AdmBorkBork*

```
('------x------','|  |  x  |  |','|  |--x--|  |')[0,1+2..0]
```

Comment: 59 bytes to do `[0,1+2..0]`

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 32 [bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#t_ps%40L%22x-%0A%7C%20%22jC%22%C2%9A%11%06%C2%9B%C3%B4%05k%C3%8B7%04%225)

```
t_ps@L"x-
| "jC"??ôkË7"5
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=t_ps%40L%22x-%0A%7C%20%22jC%22%C2%9A%11%06%C2%9B%C3%B4%05k%C3%8B7%04%225&debug=0). The above code contains some odd characters, so copying/pasting probably won't work.

Prints the first half of the pattern, followed by its reverse without the central `x`.

```
t_ps@L"x-\n| "jC"..."5   Note newline replaced with \n, encoded string replaced with ...

               C"..."    Convert encoded string to base 256 number 727558509253668163499780
              j      5   Convert to base 5, yields [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 0]
    @L                   Map each of the above to...
      "x-\n| "           ... [x, -, newline, |, space]
   s                     Concatenate into string
  p                      Print without newline
 _                       Reverse
t                        All but first character, implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 88 bytes

```cs
string a="------x------\n",b="|  |  x  |  |\n";Console.Write(a+b+"|  |--x--|  |\n"+b+a);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv1fWpyZl64QXFlckpprrZCck1hcrOBYXVySWJKZrFCWn5mi4JuYmaehqVD9v7ikCKQ20VZJFwwqIFRMnpJOkq1SjYICEFWAyRqgmLVzfl5xfk6qXnhRZkmqRqJ2kjZYDVgfVA1QLFHT@n9t7X8A)

Ungolfed:

```cs
string a = "------x------\n",
       b = "|  |  x  |  |\n";
Console.Write(a + b + "|  |--x--|  |\n" + b + a);
```

---

Here's an alternate way to do it with an anonymous function based on [adrianmp's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111277/83280) from the first Let's Play Tennis thread:

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 88 bytes

```cs
()=>{string a="------x------\n",b="|  |  x  |  |\n";return(a+b+"|  |--x--|  |\n"+b+a);};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYvBCsIwEETv/Yqlp4RafyCmoII3Tx48qIdtTCXQJpJNpdL222tIXYad4Q2jqFTO66UnY19w@VLQnQCLnaY3Kg17GEG1SASHmChgMAo@zjzhjMYyCj7ubg9A/yIOY3bqrdqttIIG5MK4rMYVAMq8TDesdrf5ppb5BBA1pD9FJrwOvbcMi7pIZRr8y8iQi1ksR2fJtXp79SZo1jDORTbP8/ID)

Ungolfed:

```cs
() =>
{
    string a = "------x------\n",
           b = "|  |  x  |  |\n";
    return(a + b + "|  |--x--|  |\n" + b + a);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download), <s>36</s> 35 bytes

**Solution:**

```
"x-| "@4\:509 425 477 0@4\:17218113
```

**Example:**

```
q)k)"x-| "@4\:509 425 477 0@4\:17218113
"------x------"
"|  |  x  |  |"
"|  |--x--|  |"
"|  |  x  |  |"
"------x------"
```

**Explanation:**

We want to generate a list of indexes into the array `"x-| "`, e.g.

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 3 3 2 3 3 0 3 3 2 3 3 2
2 3 3 2 1 1 0 1 1 2 3 3 2
2 3 3 2 3 3 0 3 3 2 3 3 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

In order to generate this we can take the base-4 representation of the flip of these numbers. This gives us:

```
425 509 509 425 477 477 0 477 477 425 509 509 425
```

We can take the distinct values and index in at the indices we require:

```
q)509 425 477 0@1 0 0 1 2 2 3 2 2 1 0 0 1
425 509 509 425 477 477 0 477 477 425 509 509 425
```

This array `1 0 0 1 2 2 3 2 2 1 0 0 1` converted to base-4 is

```
q)k)4/:1 0 0 1 2 2 3 2 2 1 0 0 1
17218113
```

So for the solution, we are just doing these steps in reverse.

```
"x-| "@4\:509 425 477 0@4\:17218113 / the solution
                        4\:17218113 / convert 17218113 into base-4
          509 425 477 0@            / index (@) into 509 425 477 0
       4\:                          / convert to base-4
"x-| "@                             / index (@) into "x-| "
```

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 46 bytes

```
/#/
!  x  !
//"/------//!/|  |/"x"#!--x--!#"x"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcahDcBADANA/lPYCbY8U0GlgrKQgN89X/XQ1XvVc9eM04tAA1x2WD@b3sB2dCSllpjfZw4)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 22 bytes

```
»°₈q8»`|- `τ3/\x+ømvøm
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%C2%BB%C2%B0%E2%82%88q8%C2%BB%60%7C-%20%60%CF%843%2F%5Cx%2B%C3%B8mv%C3%B8m&inputs=&header=&footer=)

### Alternative 22 bytes

```
»ƛ\¶≤NV»`x-| `τ3/ømvøm
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%C2%BB%C6%9B%5C%C2%B6%E2%89%A4NV%C2%BB%60x-%7C%20%60%CF%843%2F%C3%B8mv%C3%B8m&inputs=&header=&footer=)